# Can I change default volume type when create new EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

SSD storage has overspeed and over-price for our purposes.

But, when I start instance from API(like both or libcloud), it uses SSD storage automatically.

Also, I could not found options about it on AWS console.

Can I change it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Volume Type can be chosen in the AWS Console on the **Add Storage** screen:

[image: Volume Type]

It can also be selected when launching instances from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) [`run-instances` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html) by specifying `--block-device-mappings` with `VolumeType` set to one of: standard, io1, gp2, sc1, st1

There would be similar options when calling via the API, depending upon your language.

Comment: Thank you, I found option "block-device-mappings" in libcloud with EC2.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the volume type of a EC2 instance, I wrote a post how to add more size and how to change volume type, I hope it helps you. http://www.dbigcloud.com/cloud-computing/237-como-ampliar-un-volumen-ebs-en-una-instancia-ec2-en-aws.html

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with linking to or citing an external post that you wrote, the answer posted to Stack Overflow should be self-contained, including the substance of the solution, not just a citation.  Also, this external resource is in Spanish, but this is the English version of Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's the only thing I have, I only write how to... once,  you can use a translator or select your languaje in the blog.